# Reconstructing Layout for Newly Visible Components

Tags: java, android, xml, components, visibility

```
        if(v.getId()==keyboard.getId())
        {
            //DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();    
            //getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            //int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            //int editTextWidth = width*(2/3);   
            //int sendTextWidth = width*(1/3);  
            keyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            a.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            c.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            d.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //editText.setWidth(editTextWidth);
            send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //send.setWidth(sendTextWidth);
        }
```

Hello. For my main page layout, I have a few buttons displayed on my page, and one of the buttons is called `keyboard`. Once I click on the `keyboard` button, all the buttons will then be "invisible". Then an editText and a submit button will be "visible". 
(So, the user can input something using the on-screen keyboard, then submit the input). That's what the above code shows.

I'm currently having trouble constructing the layout of the newly visible components.

This is the xml code of the  editText and submit button:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="speak"
        android:text="@string/sendCommand" />
```

As you can see, I just set the width of the components to zero, so it won't interfere with the of the layout visible buttons initially on the app start up. My question is how do you set the dimension and location of the newly components that are just set to visible? Also take a look at my commented out code.

@eclipse1203: I can't use `android:visibility="gone"` because the editText and a submit button takes place in the same location of the visible buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can't use 
`android:visibility="gone"` then you should use `android:visibility="invisible"` because in this case, you views take space for layout purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I can drag the invisible components around, but I overlap the visible components to where I want the invisible components to be.

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem and if you have another problem, ask new question! :)

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using yours and eclipse1203's resizing technique.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your EditText and Button with your desired height/width, then set the attribute,

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

for each of them. If you'd really like to modify the layout within code, then you can do something like this: (ViewGroup is LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc)

```
[ViewGroup].LayoutParams params = new [ViewGroup].LayoutParams(width, height);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

EditText text = new EditText(context);
text.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I can't use `android:visibility="gone"`because the editText and a submit button takes place in the same location of the visible buttons.

Comment: You may have to change change the state of the click listeners on the button & EditText, but it works.